# Server crashes or mysql gone error once csv file data is uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, csv

I want to upload a csv file to a database, there are 10k records per file.

When I run the code, it works fine and inserts the records to the database perfectly but once all the query have been executed and all the records have been inserted, the server gives me an error: `"MYSQL GONE AWAY"`

I am using a jquery form to submit data and the same thing is happening when I run the code without ajax and jquery.

What is the issue with this, please let me know.

**What I want to happen is when all the records have been inserted, then the server would not show the error**

**ERROR:**
[image]

HERE IS CODE>.

```
$filenamecheck = 'resources/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        if (file_exists($filenamecheck)) {
            echo "3";
            die;
        } else {
        ini_set('post_max_size', '256M');
        ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '256M');
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
         { 
           echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"]; 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $ext=substr($filename,strrpos($filename,"."),(strlen($filename)-strrpos($filename,".")));        
            if($ext==".csv")
            {
                $fileupload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],'resources/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $uploadfile = "resources/".$filename;
                $file = fopen($uploadfile, "r");
                $flag = true;
                 while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                 {
                    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }

                         $coderandom = $this->generateRandomString();
                         $securitycode = $this->generateSecurityCode();
                         $nam = explode(" ",$emapData[0]);
                         $user = explode("@",$emapData[3]);
                        $data = array(
                            'uFname'      => $nam[0],
                            'uLname'      => $nam[1],
                            'uTitle'      => $emapData[1],
                            'uCompany'    => $emapData[2],
                            'uEmail'      => $emapData[3],
                            'uPassword'   => md5($coderandom),
                            'uUsername'   => $user[0],
                            'uPhone'      => $emapData[4],
                            'uStatus'      => 1,
                            'joinDate'    => date("Y-m-d"),
                            'uCode'          => $coderandom,
                            'ufb'          => 0,
                            'uReCode'      => $securitycode,
                        );
                        $this->admin_model->add_table_simple('dev_web_user',$data);
                        unset($emapData);

                 }
                 fclose($file);
                echo "1";
            } else {
                echo 'Only .CSV File allowed!';
            }
         } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Server dropped too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix, you can increase the maximal packet size limit max_allowed_packet in my.cnf file (location differs depending on Linux version), eg. set

```
max_allowed_packet = 128M
```

then restart your MySQL server:

```
 /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: we already have server of such configuration..... 
is there any way that while uploading we use such query that server keeps on connecting after one minute..... i am using codeigniter

Comment: Try to increase "wait_timeout" option, btw what is your server RAM memory and max_allowed_packet option?